# Multiple MPMoviePlayerControllers on iOS 3.2/4.0

Tags: objective-c, ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

The question is can I have two instances of MPMoviePlayerController simultaneously in one UIViewController?

I'm trying to create a smooth transition between two movies in iPad app, but when I create the second MPMoviePlayerController the playback of first one is stopped and can't be resumed. I didn't found any restriction for having multiple MPMoviePlayerControllers in Apple documentation.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Any other ideas about smooth transition between movies will be also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a restriction in the SDK doc.

**Note: Although you may create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one controller at a time may play its movie.**
Blockquote

Check here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html

It's in the Overview section.

Comment: Thanks JAG, the interest thing is that the first player stops just after creation of second one, before start playing anything on the second. Anyway I realized that it is not good idea to use two players for making smooth transition between movies. Anyone to have idea how to do it in other way?